# Mirror points at points

Tags: arcmap, point, create

I want to mirror points (airports) outside a city at the city center. Is there any tool to mirror points at points?

In one layer I defined european airports as points. In another I defined the city centers as points. Now I want to create an imaginary airport with the same distance mirrored on the city. I can do it manually for each city (line between the points and create point with same distance), but i thought that there is maybe a tool that makes it easier

Comment: More details please. A graphic would help.

Comment: Not sure about ArcMap, is there a rotate tool using an anchor point? Also, search for the term "Flip" instead of mirror, they might help.

Comment: Do you have some attribute linking the airport points to the city points, to tell which airpoint belong to which centerpoint?